# SwiftHTTP authentication error timeout

Tags: ios, http, swift, basic-authentication

I'm using [SwiftHTTP](https://github.com/daltoniam/SwiftHTTP) in an iOS application to perform basic authentication in a web server. If the authentication succeeds, everything works as expected. However, if the authentication fails (with code 401), it takes about 35 to 45 seconds for the failure handler to be called. The code is as follows:

```
    var request = HTTPTask()
    auth = HTTPAuth(username: user, password: password)
    auth!.persistence = .ForSession
    request.auth = auth
    request.requestSerializer.timeoutInterval = 5

    request.GET("http://\(ipaddr)", parameters: nil,
        success: {(response : HTTPResponse) in
            NSLog("login success")
        },
        failure: {(error: NSError, response: HTTPResponse?) in
            NSLog("login failure")
        }
    )
```

Note that the timeout value is set to 5 seconds. Checking the SwiftHTTP code, the actual request implementation boils down to:

```
var request = NSMutableURLRequest(URL: url, cachePolicy: cachePolicy, timeoutInterval: timeoutInterval)
```

I added a few debug lines in SwiftHTTP to check if `timeoutInterval` is being correctly set, and it is. I tried variations in cache policies and other configurable parameters with no changes in the result. I also opened a telnet connection to the HTTP server and sent the same request by hand, and the 401 result was returned immediately, as expected.

Any ideas why this is happening?

Comment: The authentication works when you supply the correct username and password. The problem is the unwanted delay when the authentication fails (because the user entered a wrong username or password).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When a library doesn't work in a bizarre, unexpected or nonsensical way, chances are that there's a bug in the library. If you used an unstable release or a git repository snapshot, be sure to check for fixes in the upstream tree, even if you think the library is working correctly.

So this was fixed by updating the library. `HTTPAuth` doesn't exist anymore in the current (at the time of this writing) library. It was replaced by an user-provided closure, as shown in the [library documentation](https://github.com/daltoniam/SwiftHTTP/blob/master/README.md):

```
var request = HTTPTask()
//the auth closures will continually be called until a successful auth or rejection
var attempted = false
request.auth = {(challenge: NSURLAuthenticationChallenge) in
    if !attempted {
        attempted = true
        return NSURLCredential(user: "user", password: "passwd", persistence: .ForSession)
    }
    return nil //auth failed, nil causes the request to be properly cancelled.
}
```

Answer (score 2):

It looks like `HTTPTask` handles challenges like so:

```
public func URLSession(session: NSURLSession, task: NSURLSessionTask, didReceiveChallenge challenge: NSURLAuthenticationChallenge, completionHandler: (NSURLSessionAuthChallengeDisposition, NSURLCredential!) -> Void) {
    if let a = auth {
        let cred = a(challenge)
        if let c = cred {
            completionHandler(.UseCredential, c)
            return
        }
        completionHandler(.RejectProtectionSpace, nil)
        return
    }
    completionHandler(.PerformDefaultHandling, nil)
}
```

I'd suggest you only use the credential if the `previousFailureCount` was zero, e.g.

```
public func URLSession(session: NSURLSession, task: NSURLSessionTask, didReceiveChallenge challenge: NSURLAuthenticationChallenge, completionHandler: (NSURLSessionAuthChallengeDisposition, NSURLCredential!) -> Void) {
    if let credential = auth?(challenge) {
        if challenge.previousFailureCount == 0 {
            completionHandler(.UseCredential, credential)
        } else {
            completionHandler(.RejectProtectionSpace, nil)
        }
    } else {
        completionHandler(.PerformDefaultHandling, nil)
    }
}
```

Comment: Although this isn't the real solution for the problem, it (along with @Rich's comment about HTTPAuth which seems to have been deleted) were essential to fix the application: I was using a slightly outdated version of SwiftHTTP, which had an authentication bug. I pulled from the current HEAD and it seems to be working. Thanks!